# Solve $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ $\int_{0}^{2 \cos \phi} r dr d\phi$

Tags: integration

> Solve $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ $\int_{0}^{2 \cos \phi}  r dr d\phi$  using $\int \cos^3 x dx = \frac{3}{4} \sin x + \frac{1}{12} \sin (3x)$

I tried to get $\cos^3 x$ but couldn't,

First, I integrated $\int_0^{2\cos\phi} r dr = \frac{(2 \cos \phi)^2}{3}$

Comment: $\frac{(2 \cos \phi)^2}2,$ not $\frac{(2 \cos \phi)^2}{3}.$ Then calculate the antiderivative of $\cos^2$. This is standard.

Comment: @AnneBauval but I'm trying to get the expression $\int \cos^3 \phi$ to use the formula that is provided for me, and I need to use it

Comment: Isn't it $r^2$ instead of $r$ in your left handside?